# Detectron2 difference between SOLVER.IMS_PER_BATCH and MODEL.ROI_HEADS.BATCH_SIZE_PER_IMAGE in cfg file

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, faster-rcnn, detectron

In detectron2 there seems to be two settings related to batch size in the config file.

They are

```
SOLVER.IMS_PER_BATCH and MODEL.ROI_HEADS.BATCH_SIZE_PER_IMAGE
```

I have seen both being used as batch size online and not sure how they differ. What is the difference and if they work together, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*SOLVER.IMS_PER_BATCH* is what's commonly known as batch size in deep learning and refers to the number of training examples utilized in one iteration.

*MODEL.ROI_HEADS.BATCH_SIZE_PER_IMAGE* is a [parameter](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/issues/1341) that is used to sample a subset of proposals coming out of RPN to calculate cls and reg loss during training.